# Java InputMismatchException error. What causes it?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, inputmismatchexception

What is the reason why that the following Java procedure causes a InputMismatchException error?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "hello 12345\n";
        Scanner s = new Scanner(input);
        s.next("hello ");
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: think about what the next() method does. what do you expect?

Comment: [Why don't you try to run this code?](http://ideone.com/N6Q45Q)

Comment: @Edward M.B. I expect it to find the "hello " pattern at the beginning of the string to scan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is occurring because `hello[space]` is not a token in the `String`.  The `String` is being tokenized by a whitespace delimiter so the tokens are as follows:

```
String input = "hello 12345\n";
Scanner s = new Scanner(input);

while(s.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(s.next());
}
//Outputs: Hello
//         12345
```

The error message is simply telling you that it cannot find `hello[space]` amongst the tokens, which are `hello` and `12345`.

If you want to find the pattern regardless of delimiters use, [String#findInLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findInLine%28java.lang.String%29):

```
s.findInLine("hello ");
```

Comment: @FrancescoRiccio Awesome! My favorite way to start the morning, helping someone with some code!  Thanks OP.